# Hide database password python

Tags: python, mysql

So, I am building a python login system that uses a MySQL database.
The problem is that if I give the client the password they can also access my database.
Is there a way that I can give the program the ability to add and read from the database, but not the user?

Comment: So can you show the layout of how your project works and what kind of technologies you are using. Because this question has different answers depending on what you have setup and how you want the client to access things. Like if they are accessing things through a webserver, then there should never be a need for the client to have access to your db information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this securely.
What you could consider:

- Creating a new user for your client with different access-level (read-only)
- Using revoke-able auth-keys. Not sure how to properly implement these, though.
- If sharing code on e.g. GitHub, import a `credentials.py` locally and add it to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your password and then store it to DB. You can do that by 
`hashedpass = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())`